# 301 Redirection of url Pattern in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Previously I have vbulletin forum installed on main domain. Now I have replaced it with WP blog and shifted forum to subfolder. Both WP and vB has seperate htaccess files. Please help me to redirect old forum urls to new ones.

Old url pattern:

```
www.domain.com/f1/post-title/
www.domain.com/f2/post-title/
www.domain.com/f3/post-title/
```

New url pattern:

```
www.domain.com/forums/f1/post-title/
www.domain.com/forums/f2/post-title/
www.domain.com/forums/f3/post-title/
```

Please somebody help me with rewriting rules for correct redirection. Also mention which htaccess (WP or vB) to put the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It needs to be placed on the `.htaccess` on the root folder of your domain.**

So if your root folder is `/home/youraccount/public_html/` then in the `.htaccess` in that folder.

This will redirect as you asked above, any `forum/topic` to `forums/forum/topic`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(f\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

I could use `([^/]+)` twice but since you mentioned you have a WordPress in the root now then you should need a more specific rule for the first folder like the above.

This will match the forum id aka `f1`, `f2` ... up to any amount of numbers:

```
(f\d+)
```

This will get anything not a `/` so it will get the post id and title altogether.

```
([^/]+)
```

If you have more rules inside your `.htaccess` file make sure you place this rule after `RewriteEngine on` and before any other rule, so it doesn't conflict with other rules and redirect as you asked:

```
RewriteRule ^(f\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```